# Google Sitemap issue Contao 4.4

Tags: sitemap, contao

I am using contao 4.4 instance.I have a problem in google sitemap generation.
I have a newsletter page (page type = regular ) . In that page I have some newsletter articles (with teaser) .  When I generate the sitemap, the url of these articles generated twice. When I checked the core I found a class which creates the page array for generating sitemap

> vendor/contao/core-bundle/src/Resources/contao/classes/Backend.php
>   line no 662 - 680 .

Which append 'articles/' to the articles with teaser. So the sitemap generates url

1. with articles/
2. List item

without articles/

The first one is the correct url.Second Url generate 404. How I fix the issue ?

My siteconfiguration is as follows

->created a regular page with hidden in navigation and created articles with configuration show teaser
 ->created another page and created elements as 'teaser articles' and select articles from the above page

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup. Are you talking about article teasers or newsletters?

Comment: I edited the question.Hope you got  the issue

Answer (score 0):

So your site structure is like this?

- Page 1 with multiple articles
- Page 2 with one article containing an „article teaser“ element, this page should be excluded from the sitemap

Is that correct? If yes this might be the solution:

In your „site structur“ you can EDIT Page 2: Scroll down to „Expert settings“, there is an option „Show in sitemap“ and you can select „Never show“.

Comment: I changed the settings as you suggested but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.
The url's were regenerated from the newsletter-bundle. In core bundle, the url of the article with teaser is generated. The newsletter-bundle is also contain hook for creating searchable page array. The hook regenerates the url. I wrote a function in vendor/contao/newsletter-bundle/src/Resources/contao/classes/Newsletter.php to check whether the array contain any duplicate url.

Modified function getSearchablePages() ( line 889-897
)

```
if($this->checkValidUrl($arrPages, $objItem, $strUrl)){
        $arrPages[] = sprintf($strUrl, ($objItem->alias ?: $objItem->id));
}
```

Defining new function for finding duplicate

```
public function checkValidUrl($arrPages, $objItem, $strUrl)
{
    $alias      = $objItem->alias ?: $objItem->id;
    $urlExplode = explode('%s', $strUrl);
    $articleUrl = $urlExplode[0] . 'articles';
    foreach ($arrPages as $arrPage) {
        $validarticleUrl = $articleUrl . '/' . $alias;
        if (strcasecmp($arrPage,$validarticleUrl) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug? If so, you should report that on GitHub.